# Minor bug in code written to format a text file (incorrect spacing) (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to coding so sorry if this is a silly question.

I have some text that I'm attempting to format to make it more pleasant to read, so I tried my hand at writing a short program in Python to do it for me. I initially removed extra paragraph breaks in MS-Word using the find-and-replace option. The input text looks something like this:

```
This is a sentence. So is this one. And this.
(empty line)
This is the next line
(empty line)
and some lines are like this.
```

I want to eliminate all empty lines, so that there is no spacing between lines, and ensure no sentences are left hanging mid-way like in the bit above. All new lines should begin with 2 (two) empty spaces, represented by the `$` symbol below. So after formatting it should look something like this:

```
$$This is a sentence. So is this one. And this.
$$This is the next line and some lines are like this.
```

I wrote the following script:

```
import os

directory = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/"
filename = "test.txt"
path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
with open(path,"r") as f_in, open(directory+"output.txt","w+") as f_out:
    temp = "  "
    for line in f_in:
        curr_line = line.strip()
        temp += curr_line
        #print("Current line:\n%s\n\ntemp line: %s" % (curr_line, temp))
        if curr_line:
            if temp[-1]==".": #check if sentence is complete
                f_out.write(temp)
                temp = "\n  " #two blank spaces here
```

It eliminates all blank lines, indents new lines by two spaces, and conjoins hanging sentences, but doesn't insert the necessary blank space - so the output currently looks like (missing space between the words `line` and `and`).

```
$$This is a sentence. So is this one. And this.
$$This is the next lineand some lines are like this.
```

I tried to fix this by changing the following lines of code to read as follows:

```
temp += " " + curr_line
temp = "\n " #one space instead of two
```

and that doesn't work, and I'm not entirely sure why. It *might* be an issue with the text itself but I'll check on that.

Any advice would be appreciated, and if there is a better way to do what I want than this convoluted mess that I wrote, then I would like to know that as well.

EDIT: I seem to have fixed it. In my text (very long so I didn't notice it at first) there were two lines separated by 2 (two) empty lines, and so my attempt at fixing it didn't work. I moved one line a bit further below to give the following loop, which seems to have fixed it:

```
for line in f_in:
        curr_line = line.strip()
        #print("Current line:\n%s\n\ntemp line: %s" % (curr_line, temp))
        if curr_line:
            temp += " " + curr_line
            if temp[-1]==".": #check if sentence is complete
                f_out.write(temp)
                temp = "\n "
```

<s>I also saw that an answer below initially had a bit of Regex in it, I'll have to learn that at some point in the future I suppose.</s>
Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: `temp += " " curr_line` does that compile? You probably need an operator to combine the space and curr_line, e.g. +.

Comment: Was missing an addition operator, had copied from old code. Thank you. @Rup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It's effectively the same as yours but a bit more efficient. Doesn't use string concatenation `+` `+=` (which are slow) but instead saves incomplete lines as a list. It then writes 2 spaces, each incomplete sentence joined by spaces and then a newline -- this simplifies it by only writing when a line is complete.

```
temp = []
with open(path_in, "r") as f_in, open(path_out, "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        curr_line = line.strip()
        if curr_line:
            temp.append(curr_line)
            if curr_line.endswith('.'):  # write our line
                f_out.write('  ')
                f_out.write(' '.join(temp))
                f_out.write('\n')
                temp.clear()  # reset temp
```

outputs

```
  This is a sentence. So is this one. And this.
  This is the next line and some lines are like this.
```

Comment: Explanation would be good as OP is new and is asking _how_ to do something, not just give me the code.

Comment: I managed to fix my issue myself (was stupid of me to not check my input text which had two blank lines, one containing a space, between a couple lines of text) but this was helpful as well. I didn't know that the startswith() and endswith() methods existed, or that string concatenation was slow. I'll study your solution. Thanks @FHTMitchell.